# How to show message box in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

Hi, I am using MVC Application, in that I am validating user name to prevent Duplicate names from database. Just I need to show message box or somthing

My JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CheckAvailabilty").click(function () {
            var ds = ($("#txtLoginname").val());

            $.ajax({ url: '/Home/StaffCheckAvailabilty?Staffname=' + ds,
                     type: "Post",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (rtbs) {
                         alert (message);
                         $("#txtPassword").get(0).value = rtbs[0].value;
                     }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

C# code:

```
public string rtbs;

public ActionResult StaffCheckAvailabilty(ModelGridAllFeatures model, string Staffname)
{
    var query1 = DB_Linq.TblStaffPersonalDetails
        .Where(s => s.LoginName == Staffname)
        .Select(s => new {  s.StaffName, s.ActiveFlag });

    int name = query1.Count();

    //var rtbs;
    if (name != 0)
    {
        Response.Write("Login Name already Exists");
        rtbs = "Login Name already Exists";
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Available");
        rtbs = "Available";
    }

    return Json(rtbs);
}
```

I am returing rtbs but its not showing alert message

Comment: if the success block of jQuery didnt execute , then the ajax call has failed. check from your c# code, whether your returning the proper response or not

Comment: `public ActionResult StaffCheckAvailabilty(M` and `$.ajax({ url: '/Home/StaffCheckAvailabilty?Staffname=' + ds,` dont you think there is a difference in the url and the ActionResult?

Comment: i m getting Values while in breakpoint please help @dreamweiver

Comment: I dont Know how to display it

Comment: you mean , your getting values at the server side(c# code side) once the ajax request is made ?

Comment: can u create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net  and add your ajax call there . specify the absolute url in ajax request. it will be easy to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You should alert rtbs instead message

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (rtbs) {
alert (message); 
$("#txtPassword").get(0).value = rtbs[0].value;
}
i think your returning rtbs array(); 

use this alert(rtbs[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

alert (rtbs);

Instedof,

```
 alert (message);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned is in rtbs, not message.

Try:

```
alert(rtbs);
```

If that doesn't work check you are getting to that point in the code with a simple:

```
alert("Success function reached");
```